# 'Mail Forwarding' to New Mail Server

Tags: networking, email, dns, forwarding, kerio

I have a domain registered with HostGator which i use for emails. I want to 'forward' these emails to a Kerio Connect mail server i have installed.

As it stands at the moment, i have a CNAME record which 'points' mail.mydomain.com to a dyndns account i have (dynamicip on server) and from the dyndns to the server (port forwarding (25) enabled to server).

I have deleted mx entries on the HostGator server, but attempt the Kerio webmail service and i get a HostGator 404 error, is this because dns records take 4-8 hours to update globally?

EDIT: I have now been told i still need an mx entry pointing to the server, but as you need to use a domain, i am assuming i can use dyndns? I dont want to keep making small chnages to server settings until i know for sure or ill end up losing mail.

Any help would be really great!

Thanks

Comment: You definitely do need an MX record pointing to your intended mail server; other MTAs require such a record to be able to find yours. There's no reason you can't use the DynDNS hostname in that record, so long as you're sure it will stay up to date; if at all possible, I'd recommend using a second, lower-priority MX record pointing to a backup host which will also accept mail for your domain.

Comment: That said, the presence or absence of the MX record shouldn't affect whether you can get webmail to come up at all; the DNS propagation delay may be causing that, and you also need to make sure you have ports 80 and 443 (or whatever port Kerio webmail listens on) forwarded through the router, as with port 25, in order to gain access to webmail.